# asp.net MVC google analytics on every page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

Can somebody please tell me how I can get google analytics on every page (not site wide)

I define a section Google Analytics in every page:

```
@section GoogleAnalytics{
   @using GA.NET.MVC
   @Html.GoogleAnalytics("UA-29844910-1")    
}
```

And in _Layout.cshtml

```
<head>
     @RenderSection("GoogleAnalytics", false);
</head>
```

But it comes out as text on the screen and in the body elemet for some reason althought I placed it in the head

What did i do wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo49Z.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That component was probably intended for the default ViewEngine for MVC and not Razor which does the html encoding.

Try using the `Html.Raw()` method which will not encode.

```
@Html.Raw(Html.GoogleAnalytics("UA-29844910-1"))
```

Comment: btw should i be importing the namespace in every page or is it sufficient just in the _layout?

Comment: you'll either need to define it on every page or create a namespace element in the web.config file in the views folder. `<namespaces>
        <add namespace="..."/>`